# Can not connect via AsyncSSH, error Host key is not trusted

Tags: python, ssh, asyncssh

When I run this script I receive `SSH connection failed: Host key is not trusted` error, but even connect to this host to take the key, keep to receive this error.

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys

async def run_client():
    async with asyncssh.connect('172.18.17.9', username="user", password="admin", port=9321) as conn:
        result = await conn.run('display version', check=True)
        print(result.stdout, end='')

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client())
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
    sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the `known_hosts=None` parameter to the connect method.

```
asyncssh.connect('172.18.17.9', username="user", password="admin", port=9321, known_hosts=None)
```

From asyncssh documentation here:
https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncssh.SSHClientConnectionOptions

> **known_hosts** (see Specifying known hosts) – (optional) The list of keys
> which will be used to validate the server host key presented during
> the SSH handshake. If this is not specified, the keys will be looked
> up in the file .ssh/known_hosts. If this is explicitly set to None,
> server host key validation will be disabled.

Comment: You should not disable host key validation but find a (manual or automatic) way to add the server's key to the known hosts.

Answer (score 0):

With me, it runs smoothly after inserting `known_hosts=None`

Here's my example when trying the coding sample in Ortega book:
I tried with `hostname=ip/username/password` of localCentOS, command test is ifconfig

```
import asyncssh
import asyncio
import getpass

async def execute_command(hostname, command, username, password):
    async with asyncssh.connect(hostname, username = username,password=password,known_hosts=None) as connection:
        result = await connection.run(command)
        return result.stdout
```

Comment: That's a duplicate of Roman Mirochnik, who posted it a year before you.

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate the server's public key.

Depending on your use case you can:

- Get the servers host keys, bundle them with your app and explicitly pass them to asyncssh (e.g., as string with a path to your known_hosts file).
- Manually connect to the server on the command line.  SSH will then ask you if you want to trust the server.  The keys are then added to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and AsyncSSH will use them.

Answer (score -1):

This is related but maybe not totally your salvation:

https://github.com/ronf/asyncssh/issues/132

The real question you should be asking yourself as you ask this question (help us help you) is where is it all failing? Known-hosts via analogy is like env vars that don't show up when you need them to.

EDIT: Questions that immediately fire. Host key is found but not trusted? Hmm?

EDIT2: Not trying to be harsh towards you but I think it's a helpful corrective. You've got a software library that can find the key but is not known. You're going to come across a lot of scenarios with SSH / shell / env var stuff where things you take for granted aren't known. Think clearly to help yourself and to ask the question better.

Comment: Thats not make sense for me, using Paramiko, It connects without this problem